# how to append value in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, append

I'm trying to se the evolution of my invetimens over the time and I'm stuck in a problem. When I try to loop the initial value x variation, I get a full NaN column

here's the code

```
value = 1000
total = []

for variation in df["Variation"]:
    value = value * variation
    total.append(value)
```

I've tryed the same algorithm and worked

```
list=[1,2,3,4,5]
a = 2
results = []

for x in list:
    a = a * x
    results.append(a)
```

where is the mistake?

Comment: Are you trying to append the full column of variation? What happens if in the loop you print variation?

Comment: are you trying to loop through all the values in df["Variation"]. you might need to convert df["Variation"] to a list then run the loop

Comment: I already convert variation into a list and  the list is perfectly printed, bud when I make time value still dont work. I realize that the first item of variation column ia a nan value, can be this the problem?

Comment: did it guys, nan were the problem. thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looping, a more pandas-like approach would be [**`cumprod()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Variation': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

value = 2
total = df.Variation.cumprod() * value

# 0      2
# 1      4
# 2     12
# 3     48
# 4    240
# Name: Variation, dtype: int64
```

Per the `nan` comments, note that [**`cumprod()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html) would also handle `nan` seamlessly:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Variation': [np.nan, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

value = 2
total = df.Variation.cumprod() * value

# 0      NaN
# 1      4.0
# 2     12.0
# 3     48.0
# 4    240.0
# Name: Variation, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This is pretty good and much more efficient than the other answer involving a `for` loop. +1

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
for variation in df["Variation"].tolist():
    value = value * variation
    total.append(value)
```